# how to do this ODE transformation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

Could someone please show me how the book did the following transformation? I am not able to reproduce the result shown. I show one attempt, but I tried few others. Here is screen shot of the part of the book page showing the transformation used

The [book link at google books is this](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qd4YeHCR5pcC&lpg=PA428&ots=cRJ29zXjks&dq=algorithm%20lie%20theory%20schwarz&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=algorithm%20lie%20theory%20schwarz&f=false) and the page is page number 3 in the introduction:

[image]

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}\left(  y+x\right)  +\frac{dy}{dx}\left(  \frac{dy}
{dx}-1\right)  =0 \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Since $y=u-v\left(  u\right)  $ then,

\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}-\frac{dv}{du}\frac{du}{dx} \tag{2}
\end{equation}

And%

\begin{align}
\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} &  =\frac{d^{2}u}{dx^{2}}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(  \frac
{dv}{du}\frac{du}{dx}\right)  \nonumber\\
&  =\frac{d^{2}u}{dx^{2}}-\left(  \frac{d^{2}v}{du^{2}}\left(  \frac{du}
{dx}\right)  ^{2}+\frac{dv}{du}\frac{d^{2}u}{dx^{2}}\right)  \tag{3}
\end{align}

Now Let $\frac{dv}{du}=v^{\prime},\frac{d^{2}v}{du^{2}}=v^{\prime\prime}$,
then (2) and (3) becomes

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx} &  =\frac{du}{dx}-v^{\prime}\frac{du}{dx}\\
\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} &  =\frac{d^{2}u}{dx^{2}}-\left(  v^{\prime\prime
}\left(  \frac{du}{dx}\right)  ^{2}+v^{\prime}\frac{d^{2}u}{dx^{2}}\right)
\end{align*}

Substituting the above two equations back into (1), and using the given
$x=u+v,y=u-v$ results in

\begin{align*}
\left[  \frac{d^{2}u}{dx^{2}}-\left(  v^{\prime\prime}\left(  \frac{du}
{dx}\right)  ^{2}+v^{\prime}\frac{d^{2}u}{dx^{2}}\right)  \right]  \left(
u-v+u+v\right)  +\left(  \frac{du}{dx}-v^{\prime}\frac{du}{dx}\right)  \left(
\frac{du}{dx}-v^{\prime}\frac{du}{dx}-1\right)   &  =0\\
\left[  \frac{d^{2}u}{dx^{2}}-\left(  v^{\prime\prime}\left(  \frac{du}
{dx}\right)  ^{2}+v^{\prime}\frac{d^{2}u}{dx^{2}}\right)  \right]  2u+\left(
\frac{du}{dx}\right)  ^{2}-v^{\prime}\left(  \frac{du}{dx}\right)  ^{2}
-\frac{du}{dx}-v^{\prime}\left(  \frac{du}{dx}\right)  ^{2}+v^{\prime2}\left(
\frac{du}{dx}\right)  ^{2}+v^{\prime}\frac{du}{dx} &  =0\\
2u\frac{d^{2}u}{dx^{2}}-2uv^{\prime\prime}\left(  \frac{du}{dx}\right)
^{2}-2uv^{\prime}\frac{d^{2}u}{dx^{2}}+\left(  \frac{du}{dx}\right)
^{2}-v^{\prime}\left(  \frac{du}{dx}\right)  ^{2}-\frac{du}{dx}-v^{\prime
}\left(  \frac{du}{dx}\right)  ^{2}+v^{\prime2}\left(  \frac{du}{dx}\right)
^{2}+v^{\prime}\frac{du}{dx} &  =0
\end{align*}

I do not know how to make the above same as book result.

Comment: I don't see how you get $\frac{du}{dx}=1$.

Comment: @avs Ok, I assumed because it said $v$ depends on $u$, then from $x=u+v$, when taking derivative w.r.t $x$, then we get $dv/dx=0$ ?  and so we get $1=du/dx$. But may be this is not  correct. I tried other ways, but also get stuck. That is why I am asking.

Comment: I added second attempt, that does not assume $du/dx=1$

Comment: This is not correct, because $v$ is not independent of $x$.

Comment: @avs Ok, I added new attempt. Will delete the old attempt which says $du/dx=1$

Comment: $y(x)=x$ is a solution to the original equation. But this implies that $v(u)=0$, which is not a solution to the second equation, is there something wrong with this argument?

Comment: How come the third equality on (3) be true?

Comment: @AndréPorto opps, thanks. My error. I corrected it. But as you see, I still do not know how the book did the transformation shown. I do not know how to obtain the result the book shows.

Comment: @caverac good observation. I do not know. may be the book has error? I added link to book also at top. thanks.

Comment: I think it should $ 2v'' u + 1 - v'^2 = 0 $

Comment: @Anonymous, great! Could you please show how you found this? If it just a sign difference, this is still very good.

Comment: @Nasser I changed my previous answer, found the solution!

Comment: lol, sorry 2 mistakes I missed a "be" and yeah I accidentally added a $v'$ in my method (first term) when fixing it agrees with the answer below, I did it differently maybe more rigorous and at the same time easier to understand perphas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x = u + v$ and $y = u -v$ so that

$$
x + y = 2u \quad\mbox{and}\quad x - y = 2v \tag{1}
$$

Note that

\begin{eqnarray}
dx &=& du + dv = (1 + dv/du)du = (1 + v')du \\
dy &=& du - dv = (1 - dv/du)du = (1 - v')du
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(1 - v')du}{(1 + v')du} = \frac{1 -v'}{1 + v'} \tag{2}
$$

As for the second derivative

\begin{eqnarray}
dy' &=& d\frac{1-v'}{1+ v'} = -(1 - v')(1 + v')^{-2}dv' - (1+v')dv' \\
&=& -\frac{2}{(1 + v')^2}dv' 
\end{eqnarray}

Using the fact that $dx = (1 + v')du$ we get

$$
y'' = \frac{dy'}{dx} = -\frac{2}{(1 + v')^2}\frac{dv'}{(1 + v')du} = -\frac{2}{(1 + v')^3}v'' \tag{3}
$$

Now, replacing in the original differential equation

\begin{eqnarray}
\left[-\frac{2}{(1 + v')^3}v'' \right]\left[2u \right] + \frac{1-v'}{1+v'}\left[\frac{1-v'}{1+v'} - 1 \right] = 0
\end{eqnarray}

which leads to

$$ \bbox[yellow]
{
2v''u + (1- v'^2)v' = 0
} \tag{4}
$$

**IMPORTANT**

This last equation is different from the one in the book, but I'm pretty sure there's a mistake in the book! To show that, I numerically integrate the original ODE, the second equation in the book, and equation (4). This is what I got

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your solution helped. I had little hard time following your notation of $dy'$ but I think you gave me the general idea there. +1.

Comment: @Nasser Great! Do you mean the expression before (3)? it is just $df$ where $f = dy/dx$